# LibreOffice Command Line Convert CSV to DBF

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am working on a workflow where I need to be able to batch convert CSV files into DBF files. The data in the CSV files can all be output as TEXT fields and then saved as a DBF. I have tried to get any output possible using the command line in both Mac OS and Windows 7. While I was a little more successful in Windows, I was not able to get any conversion.

```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\scalc.exe" --convert-to dbf --

infilter="csv:44,34,76,1,1/2/2/2/3/2/4/2/5/2/6/2/7/2/8/2/9/2/10/2/11/2/12/2/13/2/14/2/15/2/16/2/17/2/18/2/19/2/20/2/21/2/22/2/23/2/24/2/25/2/26/2/27/2/28/2/29/2/30/2/31/2/32/2

/33/2/34/2/35/2/36/2/37/2/38/2/39/2/40/2/41/2/42/2/43/2/44/2/45/2/46/2/47/2/48/2/49/2/50/2/51/2/52/2/53/2/54/2/55/2/56/2/57/2/58/2/59/2/60/2/61/2/62/2/63/2/64/2/65/2/66/2/67/2

/68/2/69/2/70/2/71/2,0,false,false" C:\Users\jdavidson\Desktop\DBFCONVERT\*.csv --outdir C:\Users\jdavidson\desktop\complete
```

So, I needed to have an --infilter on the command line to be able to do the conversion, but now it will only process 1 file and not batch file when using *.csv So, my next hurdle is to get over that.

The below helps to explain --infilters in more detail:

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_Lotus.2C_dBase_and_DIF_Filters

Any easier way to find the filter sequence you need is by following the below listed steps:

1. Open the CSV Manually using LibreOffice and Specify Every Detail in the import Wizard
2. Run the below macro and it will show you the filter options in an input box, so you can copy the string in to your own code

   Sub showFilterOptions
   Dim args(),i%
      args() = thisComponent.getArgs
      for i = 0 to uBound(Args())
         if args(i).Name = "FilterOptions" then inputbox "","",args(i).value
      next
   End Sub

Credit to code: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=14018

Comment: Any error messages?  Also please tell which terminal -- bash, cmd.exe, powershell et cetera.

Comment: If part of this question is the answer, then please move that part to an answer.  See [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  Also format the code better by adding four spaces in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters need to be reversed.  From https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/:

> soffice --headless --convert-to <TargetFileExtension>:<NameOfFilter> file_to_convert.xxx

Using the old windows command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\scalc.exe" --headless --convert-to dbf C:\Users\jdavidson\Desktop\DBFCONVERT\test.csv
```

This will create `test.dbf` in the current directory, which is perhaps `C:\Users\jdavidson` or, if running as administrator, `C:\Windows\system32`.  To print the working directory, enter `pwd`, and then `dir` to see the file.

In powershell, add "& " in front to execute LibreOffice.  Then enter `gci` or `ls` to see the file.

Be sure that a LibreOffice process is not already running in the background.

Comment: Jim - Thanks for getting back to me. I tried using the above and it still not outputting. I have tried other conversions to see if they would work and nothing has happened there either. I am currently using Command Prompt. I actually built the script into a batch file so that I could run the batch and have it auto convert in the end all the documents within a specific folder.  There are no error codes, but it doesn't do anything. I have searched to determine if the files are being placed elsewhere and can't find anything there either

Comment: I was able to get the following to work  `code`"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\scalc.exe" --headless --convert-to dbf C:\Users\jdavidson\Desktop\DBFCONVERT\test.csv --outdir C:\Users\jdavidson\desktop `code` but it only brings over the headers and not the data below the headers. So this is a step in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using the below code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\scalc.exe" --convert-to DBF --infilter="csv:44,34,76,1,1/2/2/2/3/2/4/2/5/2/6/2/7/2/8/2/9/2/10/2/11/2/12/2/13/2/14/2/15/2/16/2/17/2/18/2/19/2/20/2/21/2/22/2/23/2/24/2/25/2/26/2/27/2/28/2/29/2/30/2/31/2/32/2/33/2/34/2/35/2/36/2/37/2/38/2/39/2/40/2/41/2/42/2/43/2/44/2/45/2/46/2/47/2/48/2/49/2/50/2/51/2/52/2/53/2/54/2/55/2/56/2/57/2/58/2/59/2/60/2/61/2/62/2/63/2/64/2/65/2/66/2/67/2/68/2/69/2/70/2/71/2/72/2/73/2/74/2/75/2/76/2/77/2/78/2/79/2/80/2/81/2/82/2/83/2/84/2/85/2/86/2/87/2/88/2/89/2/90/2/91/2/92/2/93/2/94/2/95/2/96/2/97/2/98/2/99/2/100/2/101/2/102/2/103/2/104/2/105/2/106/2/107/2/108/2/109/2/110/2/111/2/112/2/113/2/114/2/115/2/116/2/117/2/118/2/119/2/120/2/121/2/122/2/123/2/124/2/125/2/126/2/127/2/128/2/129/2/130/2/131/2/132/2/133/2/134/2/135/2/136/2,0,false,false" C:\Users\jdavidson\Desktop\DBFCONVERT\57826001_JQSAMPLE.csv --outdir C:\Users\jdavidson\desktop\complete
```

Please note, that I needed to use DBF and include an --infilter parameter field

There are two websites in my original posting that shows helpful scripts and infilter information to help other users