# convert csv to dbase in LibreOffice in headless mode

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I can convert a csv file with dates to dbase in LibreOffice in regular mode. H_beg date and H_end_date work perfectly.

```
dbview thexport.dbf
H event id : 210721001
H name     : CCCR WEEK NIGHT 072121
H tot sect : 1
H beg date : 20210721
H end date : 20210721
H rcv date : 
H ent date : 
H aff id   : A6000220
H city     : ROCHESTER
H state    : NY
H zipcode  : 14621
H country  : USA
H sendcros : N
H scholast : N
H secrec01 : 0
```

But if try to automate the operation in headless (batch) mode, the date fields are blank!

bash script:
**libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to dbf  thexport.csv**

```
dbview thexport.dbf
H event id : 210721001
H name     : CCCR WEEK NIGHT 072121
H tot sect : 1
H beg date : 
H end date : 
H rcv date : 
H ent date : 
H aff id   : A6000220
H city     : ROCHESTER
H state    : NY
H zipcode  : 14621
H country  : USA
H sendcros : N
H scholast : N
H secrec01 : 0
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: check this it might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973790/libreoffice-command-line-convert-csv-to-dbf?rq=1

Comment: I can't do this because it makes no sense to me: infilter="csv:44,34,76,1,1/2/2/2/3/2/4/2/5/2/6/2/7/2/8/2/9/2/10/2/11/2/12/2/13/2/14/2/15/2/16/2/17/2/18/2/19/2/20/2/21/2/22/2/23/2/24/2/25/2/26/2/27/2/28/2/29/2/30/2/31/2/32/2

/33/2/34/2/35/2/36/2/37/2/38/2/39/2/40/2/41/2/42/2/43/2/44/2/45/2/46/2/47/2/48/2/49/2/50/2/51/2/52/2/53/2/54/2/55/2/56/2/57/2/58/2/59/2/60/2/61/2/62/2/63/2/64/2/65/2/66/2/67/2

/68/2/69/2/70/2/71/2,0,false,false"

Comment: what you need to try is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44976796/15336413

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'd like to delete this post because infilter="csv:44,34,76,1,1/2/2/2/3/2/4/2/5/2/6/2/7/2/8/2/9/2/10/2/11/2/12/2/13/2/14/2/15/2/16/2/17/2/18/2/19/2/20/2/21/2/22/2/23/2/24/2/25/2/26/2/27/2/28/2/29/2/30/2/31/2/32/2 /33/2/34/2/35/2/36/2/37/2/38/2/39/2/40/2/41/2/42/2/43/2/44/2/45/2/46/2/47/2/48/2/49/2/50/2/51/2/52/2/53/2/54/2/55/2/56/2/57/2/58/2/59/2/60/2/61/2/62/2/63/2/64/2/65/2/66/2/67/2 /68/2/69/2/70/2/71/2,0,false,false" gets me nowhere

Comment: Using libreoffice 6.4.7.2 at my end, gnumeric 1.12.46 reads dates etc. output by `libreoffice --convert-to dbf a.csv` and `libreoffice --convert-to xls a.csv` as expected (`--convert-to` implies `--headless` and `--invisible`). Is this a version issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install unoconv

#!/bin/bash 
cd /wherever/your_files_are/
unoconv thexport.csv thexport.dbf
unoconv tsexport.csv tsexport.dbf
unoconv tdexport.csv tdexport.dbf
```